# Principal neighborhood of Principal neighborhood is principal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an affine scheme, assume $V\subset U \subset X = \text{Spec}(A)$ such that $U$ is some principal neighborhood of $X$ (that is we have $U = D(f)$ for $f\in A$) .

$D(f)$ is also an affine scheme we have $D(f) \cong \text{Spec}(A_f)$ Assume $V \subset U$ is a principal in $U$.

I want to prove that $V$ is then also a principal neighborhood of $X$.

I found this problem in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437320/360262)

---

I don't have a good idea to prove, I have written down the definition but a bit messy.

(Where the principal open neighborhood is defined to be the complement of $V(\frak{a})$ in $\text{Spec}(A)$)

Comment: Maybe you could make your mind up on whether you want "principal" or "principle", as you have used each one three times.

Comment: Ok, corrected it. There are in fact two definition of principal open neighborhood, that I don't know how to prove the equivalence yet :)

Comment: You corrected most of it, there's still one "principle" among the "principal"s. Sorry I can't help with the math, I never got the hang of schemes.

Comment: Ok corrected it, thank you Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the post you have mentioned, let us denote principal open subsets of $X$ and $U$ by $D_X, D_U$ respectively. Suppose $V=D_U(g/f^n)$. We have $D_X(f)=\{x\in X\mid f_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}$ and $D_U(g/f^n)=\{x\in U\mid g_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}$ since $f$ is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and consequently in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ where $x\in U$. Then we can conclude $D_X(fg)=V$ because we have the following equalities:\begin{align} D_X(fg)&=\{x\in X\mid f_xg_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}\\ &=\{x\in X\mid f_x, g_x \notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}\\ &=\{x\in D_X(f)=U\mid g_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}\\&=V.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @Acrobatic ,${\frak{m}}_x$ in $D_X(f)=\{x\in X\mid f_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}
$ and $D_U(g/f^n)=\{x\in U\mid g_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}
$ are different correct? Oh they are the same since the stalk of restricted sheaf are the same as the original one.

Comment: Yes, they are essentially the same. Even if we restrict $X$ to $U$, the stalks of $X$ remain to be stalks of $U$ (if the point belongs to $U$) since they still have the universal property of inductive limit.

Comment: Got it , thank you for your help Acrobatic